# Getting subset of of data based on multiple column values

Tags: r, subset

I am trying to remove rows based on whether or not columns 2 and 3 contain 0's. I keep getting very strange results. I tried to write it without `subset` initially because I read somewhere that `subset` should only be used for small amounts of data because of the memory cost. Neither attempt worked for me however. Can someone explain what I did wrong?

```
df <- data.frame(val1=c(1,2,3), val2=c(4,0,5), val3=c(3,0,6))
subset(df,df>0,c(2,3))
data.frame(df[df[,c(2,3)]!=0])
```

starting dataframe:

```
   val1   val2   val3
1  1       4       3
1  2       0       0
3  3       5       6
```

end goal:

```
   val1   val2   val3
1  1       4       3
3  3       5       6
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using the `subset`, we create a logical index based on the 2nd and third columns.

```
subset(df, subset=!(val2==0|val3==0))
```

as `subset` argument works on columns and not on matrices.
We can also use `[` instead of `subset`.

```
df[!(df[,2]==0|df[,3]==0),]
```

Regarding the second answer in the OP's post

```
df[,c(2,3)]!=0 #returns a matrix
#      val2  val3
#[1,]  TRUE  TRUE
#[2,] FALSE FALSE
#[3,]  TRUE  TRUE
```

For subsetting rows, we need only a single logical index per each row.

---

Another option is `rowSums` (if you want to remove rows that are 0 for both column 2 and 3)

```
 df[rowSums(df[2:3])!=0,]
```

i.e.

```
df$val3[2] <- 2
```

will return all the rows with `rowSums` while the other methods return rows 1 and 3.

The equivalent option with `subset` is `&`

```
subset(df, !(val2==0 & val3==0))
```