# Automate filtering to subset data based on multiple columns

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, subset

Here is a data set I am trying to subset:

```
df<-data.frame(
id=c(1:5),
ax1=c(5,3,7,-1,9),
bx1=c(0,1,-1,0,3),
cx1=c(2,1,5,-1,5),
dx1=c(3,7,2,1,8))
```

The data set has a variable x1 that is measured at different time points, denoted by ax1, bx1, cx1 and dx1. I am trying to subset these data by deleting the rows with -1 on any column (i.e ax1, bx1, cx1, dx1). I would like to know if there is a way to automate filtering (or filter function) to perform this task. I am familiar with situations where the focus is to filter rows based on a single column (or variable).

For the current case, I made an attempt by starting with

```
mutate_at( vars(ends_with("x1"))
```

to select the required columns, but I am not sure about how to combine this with the filter function to produce the desired results. The expect output would have the 3rd and 4th row being deleted. I appreciate any help on this. There is a similar case resolved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32851588/getting-subset-of-of-data-based-on-multiple-column-values) but this has not been done through the automation process. I want to adapt the automation to the case of large data with many columns.

Comment: Sounds like a case for working with long format data if at all possible. Then it can just be something like `dflong %>% group_by(id) %>% filter(!any(value == -1))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using base R :

With `rowSums`

```
cols <- grep('x1$', names(df))
df[rowSums(df[cols] == -1) == 0, ]

#  id ax1 bx1 cx1 dx1
#1  1   5   0   2   3
#2  2   3   1   1   7
#5  5   9   3   5   8
```

Or with `apply` :

```
df[!apply(df[cols] == -1, 1, any), ]
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `filter()` with `across()`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  filter(across(ends_with("x1"), ~ .x != -1))

#   id ax1 bx1 cx1 dx1
# 1  1   5   0   2   3
# 2  2   3   1   1   7
# 3  5   9   3   5   8
```

---

It's equivalent to `filter_at()` with `all_vars()`, which has been superseded in `dplyr 1.0.0`.

```
df %>%
  filter_at(vars(ends_with("x1")), all_vars(. != -1))
```

Comment: +1 for @Darren's solution.  As a broader comment, I think you will find this and other problems easier to solve if your dataset is [tidy](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyr/vignettes/tidy-data.html).  To an extent, tidyness depends on context, but here something similar to a tibble with columns for `ID`, `Time` and `Value` would probably do the trick.

Comment: @Darren Tsai thanks! I get this error " could not find function across".  I would like to know if the across function comes from a specific package?

Comment: @TRichard `across()` is a new function in dplyr 1.0.0. You can try to update your dplyr version and `across()` will work.

Answer (score 0):

Using `filter_at`;

```
 library(tidyverse)

 df<-data.frame(
   id=c(1:5),
   ax1=c(5,3,7,-1,9),
   bx1=c(0,1,-1,0,3),
   cx1=c(2,1,5,-1,5),
   dx1=c(3,7,2,1,8))
 df

 df %>%
   filter_at(vars(ax1:dx1), ~. != as.numeric(-1))

 # id ax1 bx1 cx1 dx1
 # 1  1   5   0   2   3
 # 2  2   3   1   1   7
 # 3  5   9   3   5   8
```