# add column based on condition on several columns

Tags: r

I have a large dataset of a survey. Now I want to add a column categorizing some of the participants based on their answers on some of the questions.

I have the following dataframe:
*(in reallity a lot wider than that, about 120 columns)*

```
age item1 item2 item3 ... item9 question1 question2 ...
18      0     0     4 ...     0         1         2 ...
19      0     4     0 ...     0         5         6 ...
20      4     4     0 ...     4         1         2 ...
21      0     0     4 ...     0         3         4 ...
```

I have the following list of items I want to consider for my categorization: *(in reality a lot longer than just 3 items)*

```
selector <- c("item1", "item2", "item9")
```

Now I want to select every participant (row) that matches the criterion "at least on item out of my list was rated higher than 3" and add a tag to the row.
I cannot use something like "starts_with" because I don't want all the items starting with "item" but only the ones in my list.

Result should look like this:

```
age item1 item2 item3 ... item9 question1 question2 ... category
18      0     0     4 ...     0         1         2 ... FALSE
19      0     4     0 ...     0         5         6 ... TRUE
20      4     4     0 ...     4         1         2 ... TRUE
21      0     0     4 ...     0         3         4 ... FALSE
```

How do I achieve this without writing out a conditional statement for every single column I want to consider?

Edit: In a first version of ths question I was told that [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32851588/getting-subset-of-of-data-based-on-multiple-column-values) answers mine, which it does not. This is because I do explicitly not want to name all the columns in the condition but get them from a sigle place like a list. The answer in the afore mentioned question only works if you want to subset a dataset and if you do not have an extensive list of conditions to check. So what can I do?

Comment: Something like:  `d[ rowSums(d[, selector] > 3) > 0, ]`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following solution:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df %>%
  mutate(category = pmap_lgl(df %>% 
                           select(selector), ~ any(c(...) > 3)))

  age item1 item2 item3 item9 question1 question2 category
1  18     0     0     4     0         1         2    FALSE
2  19     0     4     0     0         5         6     TRUE
3  20     4     4     0     4         1         2     TRUE
4  21     0     0     4     0         3         4    FALSE
```

**Data**

```
df <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = "
                 age item1 item2 item3 item9 question1 question2
18      0     0     4     0         1         2
19      0     4     0     0         5         6
20      4     4     0     4         1         2
21      0     0     4     0         3         4")
```