# label row in dataframe based on several conditions stored in list

Tags: r

I have a large dataset of a survey. Now I want to add a column categorizing some of the participants based on their answers on some of the questions.

I have the following dataframe (df):
*(in reallity a lot wider than that, about 120 columns)*

```
age item1 item2 item3 ... item9
18      0     0     4 ...     0
19      0     4     0 ...     0
20      4     4     0 ...     4
21      0     0     4 ...     0
```

I have the following list of items I want to consider for my categorization: *(in reality a lot longer than just 3 items)*

```
selector <- c("item1", "item2", "item9")
```

Now I want to select every participant (row) that matches the criterion "at least on item out of my list was rated higher than 3" and add a tag to the row.
I cannot use something like "starts_with" because I don't want all the items starting with "item" but only the ones in my list.

Result should look like this:

```
age item1 item2 item3 ... item9 category
18      0     0     4 ...     0   FALSE
19      0     4     0 ...     0   TRUE
20      4     4     0 ...     4   TRUE
21      0     0     4 ...     0   FALSE
```

I have come this far:

```
df %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(category = ifelse(selector > 3, TRUE, FALSE)
```

But this does not work due to the selector not being the right thing here. (error: "must be size 1 not 3")
Of course I could do this:

```
df %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(category = ifelse(item1 > 3 | item2 > 3 | item9 > 3, TRUE, FALSE)
```

But this would be very tidysome with a big number of items to consider.

How can I select something in the ifelse() statement coming from a variable?

How do I achieve this labeling without writing out a conditional statement for every single column I want to consider?

Note: In a first version of ths question I was told that [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32851588/getting-subset-of-of-data-based-on-multiple-column-values) answers mine, which it does not. This is because I do explicitly not want to name all the columns in the condition but get them from a sigle place like a list. The answer in the afore mentioned question only works if you want to subset a dataset and if you do not have an extensive list of conditions to check. So what can I do?

Comment: `df$category <- apply(df[selector], 1, function (x) any(x >3))`

Comment: Also a note: you don't need to write `ifelse(item1 > 3 | item2 > 3 | item9 > 3, TRUE, FALSE)`. You can just write `item1 > 3 | item2 > 3 | item9 > 3`.